# Syntax error in Sqlite query while adding foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite

I got syntax error in my sqlite query while executing the query

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ABC+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT_MATCH_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_MATCH_ID) REFERENCES "+TABLE_DEF+" (MATCH_ID), EVENT_ID TEXT, EVENT_TYPE TEXT, EVENT_MINUTE TEXT," +
                        "EVENT_TEAM TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER_ID TEXT, EVENT_RESULT TEXT)");
```

Error is " syntax error near EVENT_ID". Can anybody help me to trace the error?

Answer (score 2):

Put your table constraints such as foreign key definitions after the column specifications:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ABC+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT_MATCH_ID INTEGER, EVENT_ID TEXT, EVENT_TYPE TEXT, EVENT_MINUTE TEXT," +
                    "EVENT_TEAM TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER_ID TEXT, EVENT_RESULT TEXT, " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_MATCH_ID) REFERENCES "+TABLE_DEF+" (MATCH_ID))");
```

Answer (score 2):

The table constraints go after the column definition:https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Try this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ABC+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT_MATCH_ID INTEGER, EVENT_ID TEXT, EVENT_TYPE TEXT, EVENT_MINUTE TEXT," +
                "EVENT_TEAM TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER_ID TEXT, EVENT_RESULT TEXT, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_MATCH_ID) REFERENCES "+TABLE_DEF+" (MATCH_ID))");
```

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ABC+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT_MATCH_ID INTEGER, EVENT_ID TEXT, EVENT_TYPE TEXT, EVENT_MINUTE TEXT," +
                    "EVENT_TEAM TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER TEXT, EVENT_PLAYER_ID TEXT, EVENT_RESULT TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_MATCH_ID) REFERENCES "+TABLE_DEF+" (MATCH_ID))");
```